# Sorting arbitrary numeric data and leave whitespaces for the missing values

Tags: sorting, excel, vba

I need to sort the numeric data in a row/column while leaving space of missing values at scale of 1-5.

Like:

```
A        B  
13245    1_2_3_4_5  
152....  1_2_ _ _5
```

Comment: So... what? You need it, fine. But what have you done? What did you try? What is the logic you need to employ, if any? Are you sure it's always 1 to 5? Kindly be clearer with what you want and provide complete information about your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this UDF:

```
Function ModSort(Str As String) As String
    Res = ""
    For Iter = 1 To 5
        If InStr(1, Str, CStr(Iter)) Then
            Hold = CStr(Iter) & "_"
        Else
            Hold = " _"
        End If
        Res = Res & Hold
    Next Iter
    Res = Left(Res, 9)
    ModSort = Res
End Function
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Let us know if this helps.

Comment: +1! My idea was to use basis string "1_2_3_4_5" and replace all numbers that are not in `A1` cell with space (as OP mentioned). But still can't figure out how to do it using only built-in formulas:)

Comment: @simoco: Would be really nice to see something like that. Admittedly, ever since I learned VBA, I started sucking at formulas so badly, I can't even write an array formula to save my life. I also thought of either a `SUBSTITUTE` or `REPLACE` approach. Can't imagine it though. :)

Comment: thank you very much for your effort..... great one

Comment: Kindly mark the answer as accepted if it helped you. This is how we say thanks in SO.

Answer (score 0):

Not meant as a serious answer (UDF seems good enough) but appears possible with a formula:

```
=IF(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,1,""))<LEN(A2),"1_"," _")  
&IF(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,2,""))<LEN(A2),"2_"," _")  
&IF(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,3,""))<LEN(A2),"3_"," _")  
&IF(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,4,""))<LEN(A2),"4_"," _")  
&IF(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,5,""))<LEN(A2),"5",)
```

Comment: thank you very much for your effort..... great & Easy one